# C*-Algebra generated by self-adjoint Elements of commutative unital C*-Algebra

Tags: compactness, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I want to proof the following theorem:

Let A be a commutative unital C*-Algebra and $a_1, ..., a_n\in A_{sa}$. Then $C^*(1_A, a_1, ..., a_n)\subseteq A$ is *-isomorphic to $C(\Omega )$ for a compact subset $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$.

What may I say about the case $a_1, ..., a_n \in A_+$?

What if $a_1, ..., a_n \in A$ arbitrary?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ denote the set of non-zero multiplicative linear functionals on $B := C^{\ast}(1_A, a_1, a_2,\ldots, a_n)$, and let
$$
Y := \prod_{i=1}^n \sigma(a_i)
$$
Since each $a_i$ is self adjoint, $Y \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Now consider the map
$$
\mu : X \to Y \text{ given by } \tau \mapsto (\tau(a_1), \tau(a_2),\ldots , \tau(a_n))
$$
Since $\tau(1) = 1$ for all $\tau \in X$, it follows that $\mu$ is injective (Why?). It is also clearly continuous (note that $X$ is equipped with the weak-$\ast$ topology). Since $X$ is compact and $Y$ is Hausdorff, $\mu$ induces a homeomorphism
$$
X \to \mu(X) =: \Omega
$$
Hence,
$$
B \cong C(X) \cong C(\Omega)
$$
So clearly if each $a_i \in A_+$, then $\Omega \subset (\mathbb{R}_+)^n$

Comment: Thanks for your help! You left out the third question but with your help I think I can solve it on my own: If $a_1, ..., a_n \in A$ arbitrary $\mu$ defined as above isn't injective. But I think $\mu': \Omega(B) \rightarrow Y \times Y^*, \tau\mapsto (\tau(a_1), ..., \tau(a_n), \tau(a_1^*), ..., \tau(a_n^*))$ is so we get $B \cong C(\Omega')$ for $\Omega' \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$ compact. Is this true?

Comment: If $\tau$ is a multiplicative homomorphism, then $\tau(a^{\ast}) = \overline{\tau(a)}$, so $Y^{\ast}$ is unnecessary. The same map $\mu$ I defined continues to be injective. However, the image $Y$ is contained in $\mathbb{C}^n$ and not $\mathbb{R}^n$